# Multi-dot paths in zsh, like `cd ....`

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion, zsh-zle

All shells understand these commands:

```
$ cd .
$ cd ..
```

And zsh will also understand:

```
$ cd ...
$ cd ....
```

Provided you say:

```
$ alias -g ...='../..'
$ alias -g ....='../../..'
```

Now, how can I make it do proper tab-completion when I've started typing `cd ..../<TAB>`? I recall it was implemented in oh-my-zsh but I've stopped using it now.

It would also be appreciated if it would work not only for `cd`, say I want to execute `cat ..../a/b/..../c/d | less`.

Comment: What is alias -g?

Comment: @FelixDombek did you get an answer regarding [-g](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_8.html) flag?

Answer (score 10):

I wasn't happy with the other answers so I spent a bit of time getting something more to my liking. The following will expand the dots when you hit <kbd>↵</kbd> (return) or <kbd>↹</kbd> (tab), not as you type the dots.

```
function expand-dots() {
    local MATCH
    if [[ $LBUFFER =~ '(^| )\.\.\.+' ]]; then
        LBUFFER=$LBUFFER:fs%\.\.\.%../..%
    fi
}

function expand-dots-then-expand-or-complete() {
    zle expand-dots
    zle expand-or-complete
}

function expand-dots-then-accept-line() {
    zle expand-dots
    zle accept-line
}

zle -N expand-dots
zle -N expand-dots-then-expand-or-complete
zle -N expand-dots-then-accept-line
bindkey '^I' expand-dots-then-expand-or-complete
bindkey '^M' expand-dots-then-accept-line
```

Comment: do you mind if I repoify the code in this answer into a zsh-package?

Comment: @Tarrasch, sure, go ahead.

Comment: Thanks! I [modified it slightly](https://github.com/parkercoates/dotfiles/blob/master/.zsh/expand-multiple-dots.zsh#L5) to have it only apply when the `...` comes at the beginning of the line or after a space. This keeps it from breaking `git` or `p4` commands, at the cost of it not working in the middle of a path, but I never type things like `cd a/b/..../y/z` so I don't mind.

Answer (score 7):

What I did to to deal with the same problem is to just let zsh fill in `../..` when I type  `...` and it makes sense to expand it in that way. It may suit you (or not :-P):

```
if is-at-least 5.0.0 && [[ ! $UID -eq 0 ]]; then                                                                                                                             
  ## http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2010/msg00769.html                                                                                                                       
  function rationalise-dot() {                                                                                                                                             
    local MATCH # keep the regex match from leaking to the environment                                                                                                   
    if [[ $LBUFFER =~ '(^|/| |      |'$'\n''|\||;|&)\.\.$' && ! $LBUFFER = p4* ]]; then                                                                                  
        #if [[ ! $LBUFFER = p4* && $LBUFFER = *.. ]]; then                                                                                                               
        LBUFFER+=/..                                                                                                                                                     
    else                                                                                                                                                                 
        zle self-insert                                                                                                                                                  
    fi                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                        
zle -N rationalise-dot                                                                                                                                                   
bindkey . rationalise-dot                                                                                                                                                
bindkey -M isearch . self-insert                                                                                                                                         
fi
```

I also have an alias for `...`, but it is not global.

Notice I check if the command line starts with `p4` (the Perforce command line tool) and do not mess with it in that case, as Perforce arguments often involve literal `...`. If you do not use `p4` you can obviously remove that check.

Comment: This is a useful trick, but not exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: Here is an improved version, which also works for aliases that use `p4` or `git`: https://github.com/blueyed/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/functions/rationalise-dot

Answer (score 5):

A good option is [manydots-magic](https://github.com/knu/zsh-manydots-magic), which expands `...` into `../..`, etc. but does it intelligently. See the link above for more details, but briefly:

- It allows you to revert the expansion with a single <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (if it were the last thing you typed).

  - But it won't revert *explicitly* typed `../..`
- You can use it inline, e.g. `cd a/b/..../y/z`.
- Nevertheless, it won't expand when it doesn't make sense, e.g. `git log branch...`
- It *will* expand when it might make sense, but revert when you type more. e.g.

  - `git diff ...` -> `git diff ../..`
  - `git diff ...b` -> `git diff ...b` (for `git diff ...branch`)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `compinit` and use `_expand_alias` as completer. Here is an example:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _ignored _expand_alias
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

`_complete _ignored` is the default setting for `completer`, you could set it to only `_expand_alias` but then completion would only work for aliases.

If `compinit` is already configured in your `~/.zshrc`, then you just need to add `_expand_alias` into the list for `completer`, for example:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _approximate _expand_alias
```

By default `_expand_alias` expands global and and regular aliases, if you do not want to expand regular aliases, set:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' regular false
```

**Note:** This of course works only, where global aliases would work. So they would not be expanded as part of an entire path like `a/b/..../c/d`

Comment: I couldn't get `cd .../<TAB>` to work after following these steps: (1) remove `.zshrc`, (2) open zsh, (3) paste in those 3 consecutive lines from your answer, (4) `alias -g ...='../..'`. Still `cd .../<TAB>` is ignoring the tab-key. Is this working on your machine? Am I missing a step?

Comment: @Tarrasch If you are pressing *<Tab>* after `.../` it will not work if you define `...` as the alias, as the `/` is not part of the alias. Either press *<Tab>* directly after `...` or just define `alias -g .../='../..'`, too.

Comment: What I get is that `<Tab>`-key expands `.../` to `../../`, which is not what I want. I want it to *stay* as `.../` but bring up completion options as if I had typed `../../<Tab>`. I'm quite sure omz had this behavior ...

Comment: I'm unsure how this would work, as global aliases are not expanded - or even recognized as such - inside words. That means, even if you have `...` mapped as above, `/a/b/.../c` will not land you in `/c`.