# Unix terminal, "cd .." for a specific number of directories

Tags: shell, unix

Let's suppose we have this directory structure:

```
/home/myuser/dir_1/sub_1/sub_2/sub_3
```

and I want to traverse from sub_3 to dir_1, what I need to do is

```
cd ../../..
```

My question is, isn't there something shorter?
I mean something like:

```
cd -t 3
```

where you can tell the shell how many directories you want to go back.

Comment: dup: http://superuser.com/questions/281797/is-there-a-command-for-going-back-a-number-of-steps-in-a-directory-without-usin/281799

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Build the path using `printf` then `cd` to it:

```
cdup() {
    # $1=number of times, defaults to 1
    local path
    printf -v path '%*s' "${1:-1}"
    cd "${path// /../}"
}
```

Use as:

```
cdup 4 # to go up four directories
cdup 1 # to explicitly go up one directory
cdup   # to implicitly go up one
```

Has the nice property that `cd` is called once, regardless of how big N is.

Comment: Winner because of the "cd is called once". Added to my .bash_profile (I have a mac, should be .bashrc for unix/linux users) and it works like a charm. My '.' key thanks you @bishop.

Answer (score 1):

for i in {0..2}; do cd ..; done

Comment: This is *more* characters than `cd ../../..` -- defeats the point, no?

Answer (score 1):

```
cd ~/dir_1
```

Should do the same as well.  Of course, that only works when you are going somewhere in your home directory....

Answer (score 0):

I just a couple of weeks ago made a Zsh completion function to do this. [The answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41420448/83264).

It allows you to type `cd .....` then hit tab (or return) to expand the dots into the relevant number of directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can put cdup in your .bashrc

```
 alias cdup='_(){ a=$1;while ((a--));do cd ..;done;};_'
```

Or

```
cdup() { a=$1;while ((a--));do cd ..;done; }
```

Test to make two cd ..

```
cdup 2
```

Comment: Why would you write this as an alias enclosing a temporary function rather than just creating a function?

Comment: @Charles Duffy. I use a temporary function inside alias because it's easier to program.

Comment: `cdup() { a=$1;while ((a--));do cd ..;done; }` is *harder* to write than `alias cdup='_(){ a=$1;while ((a--));do cd ..;done;};_'`? How so?

Comment: @Charles Duffy. Your solution doesn't work  inside .bashrc (alias cdup=...).

Comment: Untrue; function definitions are **absolutely** supported inside `.bashrc`. There's no need to use the `alias` keyword at all.

Comment: Moreover, unlike an alias, you can export a function to the environment, thereby making it available to subprocesses.

Comment: @Charles Duffy. Ok its work like function definitions inside .bashrc. Thank's a lot.